# I am having issues looping through my VBA code and putting the correct variable in specific cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am a little new to VBA

How the macro works is when someone inputs in the error child_variations.color: Update attribution to reflect the correct data or more than 1 of these errors into a cell. The macro will split in the string at the colon into separate cells (that part of the macro is working correctly). Then the macro needs to loop through each cell and if the string in the cell contains an underscore (*) then that string is saved in a variable and is put into a cell. If the string does not contain an underscore (*), then it is saved into a different variable.

The issue that I am having is putting the string together into separate cells. I want to put all of the text that is on the left of the colon into one string and one cell. I also want to put the text that is right of the colon in another string and cell. I have tried to use the loop and the if statements below, but all of the text to the left and right of the colon is being put into the same cell.

Below I have before along with how the cells are supposed to look in the spreadsheet.

Before
child_variations.color:Update attribution to reflect the correct data.
digital_assets.images.primary_image_url:Primary image does not align with alternate image(s).

How it should look
child_variations.color  Update attribution to reflect the correct data.

Any help that you can give to me would help out greatly!

```
        Sub delimted()
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Dim cel As range
     Dim str As String
     Dim str_is_blank As String
     Dim my_range As range
     Dim no_of_rows As Long
     Dim i As Long
     Dim str_with_special_char As String
     Set my_range = Sheets("Setup").range("L7:Z500")
     no_of_rows = my_range.Rows.Count
     Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setup")
     ws.range("I7:I500").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns _
        Destination:=range("L7:L500"), _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, _
        comma:=False, _
        Space:=True, _
        Other:=True, _
        OtherChar:=":"
  For Each cel In my_range.Cells
        If InStr(cel.Value, "_") > 0 Then
                str_with_special_char = str_with_special_char & " " & cel.Value
                range("I7").Value = str_with_special_char
        ElseIf Not InStr(cel.Value, "_") Then
            str = str & " " & cel.Value
            range("J7").Value = str
        ElseIf IsEmpty(cel.Value) Then
            str_is_blank = str_is_blank & cel.Value
        End If
Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: Your friend will be the split function: Dim mystring() - myString() = split(cel.value,"_") - MyString will have at least one value myString(0) if there is no underscrore in the text. Or it has more values - one for each part where underscore was found.

Comment: Thank you for the response and help, I really appreciate it! The only problem is that I am having issues putting the string back together. The code below works perfectly to break the delimiter into another cell, but what if there are 2 of the same delimiters in one cell? How do I make sure that all of the text that has an underscore _ and is to the left of the : go into a specific cell?

Comment: So that if this is in cell A -> Hello_World:Hi Josh Hello_OverStack:Hi Mom. The Hello_World and Hello_OverStack go into column B and Hi Josh and Hi Mom go into column C?

Comment: Thank you again for your help

Comment: Finally, I want to keep all of the text to the left of the : in 1 cell

Answer (score 0):

first of all can you show a column with your data and a column with the desired result so I can make a try?

Second:

```
ws.range("I7:I500").Select
```

will slow down your macro, instead you can use:

```
ws.range("I7:I500").TextToColumns _
    Destination:=range("L7:L500"), _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
    Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, _
    comma:=False, _
    Space:=True, _
    Other:=True, _
    OtherChar:=":"
```

But anyway if you want to put some words with "_" in a range and other in another range you can use a loop, it is more easy to do and understand.

For example if you want to split the words with "_" then you can use something like this

```
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("L7:L500").Cells
If InStr(cell, "_") > 0 Then
   cell.Offset(0, 1) = Left(cell, WorksheetFunction.Find("_", cell))
   cell.Offset(0, 2) = Right(cell, Len(cell) -WorksheetFunction.Find("_",cell))
Else
   cell.Offset(0, 3) = cell
End If
Next cell
```

and if we suppose that the column L is with a word like "Hello_World" then in the column M you will have "Hello_" and in the column N you will have "World", the next column will have all those words that dont have any "_"